# How to access the device camera in KendoUI Mobile and phonegap build

Tags: kendo-ui, phonegap-build, kendo-mobile

me again...

I'm building a multi platform mobile app using KendoUI mobile. I need to access the device camera but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to do so.

I have tried the `<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">` but it doesn't work, once the package is built in phonegap build (and in the emulator) it only opens a choose file dialog.

Does anyone know how to access the device camera in a KendoUI mobile "native" app??

Regards,
Devon Britton.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this documentation on how to Capture image from PhoneGap: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera .

You need to use the camera.getPicture method take a picture using your device.

Kendo Mobile has nothing built in for native features. The PhoneGap APIs need to be used in the same way u use it in pure JS code.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've tried to incorporate phonegap into my application but I'm getting the following error...                                                     deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova-2.7.0.js:6672
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady cordova-2.7.0.js:6665
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady cordova-2.7.0.js:6665
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady

Comment: You need to build the android phonegap app (that is make an apk), that you later on install on the device. Since javascript can't directly access the hardware without the rest of the phonegap API.